# Estilado de un gráfico de Trading View

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día,estoy intentando customizar el estilado de un gráfico de trading view, el mismo es el siguiente: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

Qué necesito? Poder estilar esta barra de arriba: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, estilar botones, colores de los botones y de los hovers, etc. Se puede? no consigo información, tampoco me deja acceder vía DOM. Estoy trabajando con React.

Comment: Te sugerimos mirar [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es una pregunta un poco difícil de contestar ya que depende de qué quieres estilar o cómo quieres que se vea. Lo que puedes hacer es abrir el inspector y hacer cambios en el CSS de cada elemento. Si no sabes como se hace, con la tecla F12, o click derecho + inspeccionar. Y con la flecha que está en inspector (arriba a la izquierda) seleccionas elementos en la página. Luego en el código CSS has cambios, seguro consigues videos en youtube de como hacerlo si nunca lo has hecho.

Pero creo que la mayoría de los botones son SVG y no son fáciles de estilar, pero seguro habrá otras cosas que sí (bordes, background, fonts, etc...).

Comment: Lo que necesito estilar es el chart que tiene el link que dejé en descripción y necesito estilar los botones, no importa el diseño, necesito saber si se puede acceder ya que es un iframe que retorna un html y si bien con las devtools lo puedo estilar, no consigo acceder mediante código, esa es la problemática principal